# File doesn't belong to this project - PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

**UPDATE**

Asked the question on the PhpStorm site.

---

[image: Staps 1 by 1[1]
When I press <kbd>Ctr + Shift + N</kbd> to navigate in my project files it can only find some off my files in the directory. So most off the files do not belong to the project. How to make it so my directory with all the files becomes 1 project again?

Also it looks like some off the files are on `C:\Users\Username\Projects\Website` and other files are on `Z:\Projects\Website`

It's a short question I hope I explained it right, and if I need to give more information about something ask/tell me. (also I don't know which tags I have to use)

[image: Does not belong in this project picture]

Comment: Just open project from original location (which seems to be `C:\Users\Username\Projects\Website`) and do not use mounted drives/symbolic links (`Z:\Projects\Website` in your case).

Comment: @LazyOne  When I try to use ' Ctr + Shift + N ' it now loads for longer then 5 minuts so I stopped that (idk if thats a good sign cause first it only found 1 file) 
When I try to replace in all files with  ' Ctr + Shift + R ' it finds not all the words, maybe half of them. When I change the scope directory to Z:\Projects\Website it finds the other half.
Is ther a way to put it all together?

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- should help in such "suddenly stopped working" situations.

Comment: I tried the File | Invalidate Caches... but it still looks like its loading for a long time and still does the same with everything. Previous time it took 5 minuts and still didn't find anything (Then I just stopped the searching).

Comment: Made a little Update in my code cause I saw that the program made 2 projects now

Comment: About 2 project: Just hover over unwanted project and either click on "x" icon or just press `Delete` key.

Comment: I did delete the Z:/ one. 
The thing I mean with "Does not belong in this project"  is added to my question. Maybe that will explain itself.

Comment: Do not open any files from `Z:\Projects\Website` -- only use `C:\Users\Username\Projects\Website` -- check the files you have opened; the paths you are searching etc. The message/behaviour itself is correct -- IDE warns you from accidentally modifying non-project files. Plus, IDE does not follow symlinks/mapped drives and does not know that `C:\Users\Username\Projects\Website\file.html` is the same as `Z:\Projects\Website\file.html` -- from IDE point of view those 2 are two different files.

Comment: Added a picture on top, the file where I search in is in the good path (C:\Users\Username\Projects\Website\file.php).

Comment: Need to see whole Find/Replace window -- maybe you have selected wrong scope or something. My suggestion right now: 1) close this project in IDE so you see "Welcome" screen 2) Delete this project from the "recent list" on the left side 3) Go to your project folder and delete `.idea` subfolder (that's your project settings) 4) use "Open" action from "Welcome" screen and point to the project root folder -- it will create brand new project from those files (as previous settings we have deleted in #3) -- see how it will behave now.

Comment: @LazyOne I just did all staps, still same problem. 
Updated the image so you see the scope and you can see I choose it from the right path.

Comment: 1) Preview window only shows up to 100 matches for `Z:\` -- it might be more (you will see them when you click "Search" button and results will be listed in dedicated tool window 2) Right now I do not have any useful explanation to what I see on your screenshots

Comment: 3) Could you please try actual latest version (which is 2016.3.2) .. or maybe even 2017.1 EAP build? They can be run in parallel (store global settings in separate folders) -- they may have this fixed (whatever this might be). Otherwise -- consider submitting support ticket and provide all the info they will ask (`idea.log` file to start with) to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us --"SUBMIT A REQUEST" link at the top. I cannot make much out of this with limited access to your info.

Comment: thanks for your help.
I can't download the new version right now since that I need the adminstrator inlog stuff for that (and my boss is not at work now..).

I will make a ticket, do you think it's smart to send them the link of this topic?

Comment: Also I don't think its from this version, I got this version also on my laptop were it does not do this.

Comment: 1) The support tickets are private -- only JB stuff van see them (and I'm not one of them). If it would be Issue Tracker (Bug, Feature Request or alike) then yes -- it's public so anyone can see. So right now there is no much sense in publishing the ticket number (but will not hurt either)

Comment: 2) For me this looks like some misconfiguration from your end (be it IDE config or file system) or some plugin that helps messing things up. Support guys could check your logs and may see what is going wrong. they may also offer TeamViewer or alike session and quickly see it with their own eyes as (from my own experience when I'm doing something like that when helping with debug -- you can see things that other person thinks completely unrelated or working normal .. or when person completely ignores some of your questions -- and that makes HUGE difference)

Comment: Right now I may only suggest to once again try the same `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE. No other reasonable ideas than that. (I could try TeamViewer session myself .. but since you have no admin rights on that PC you may not be able to run it anyway).

Comment: Could be misconfiguration since this is only the second time i configured it and the first time was with my teacher :P     Also I hope they won't need teamviewer since I need to download it then and dont have the administrator password

Comment: And tried the File | Invaldidate Caches thing 2 times didn't work. (meanwhile I changed everything I wanted to change allready by hand, but it would still be nice if I wanted to change something else some time)

Answer (score 6):

If someone is experiencing this problem with the PhpStorm 2021 version, try these steps:

1. Close the IDE.
2. Go the project directory and delete .idea folder.
3. Restart the IDE.

For me, the IDE created a new .idea folder and recognized all files as the part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reopening the project? That sometimes does solve my problems.

Comment: Yep i tried that a couple of times (also question is edited a little bit)

Comment: So they are in multiple drives and should be in just one drive? Have you close the project, tried deleting the (hidden) .idea folder and ropened the project again? PHPStorm should be creating the .idea folder again, but your project settings will get lost.

Comment: I just deleted it but nothing changed. Also the 2 drives are actually the same, they have the same files on them. (hard to explain, its on my work so every pc gets his own drive 'F:/, P:/, Z:/ etc' and every pc has locally his own C:/ drive)

Comment: So these F:/, P:/, Z:/ are network drives? And did you close the project before deleting the .idea folder? It doesn't actually delete the folder when the project is still open.

Comment: I think it are network drives yes.
And yes I did it with the project closed.

Comment: Do you have "Project" selected on top of the navigation view? See: http://imgur.com/HWUhMPY

Comment: Yep, it stands on project.
I also tried 'File | New project from existing file' but that also didn't do much

Comment: Alright and just to be sure, when you're searching for a file, the checkbox "include non-project files" is not on? See: http://imgur.com/3n3GCfx

Comment: Or you might have a filter enabled at that view?

Comment: I don't think I selected a filter since I never used a filter in PHPstorm.
And I can see all the files on the left. But when I search for them with 'Ctr+shift+n' it wont find them. Or when I want to replace something in every file with 'ctrl+shift+r' it wont find the word to replace. (Sometimes if I change the directory in the scope it will find it but not allways)

Comment: Well really not sure what the problem could be then, but you really shouldn't be storing project files (or a project) on a network as JetBrains doesn't support that. So if there are files stored on your network drive you should look for some workaround I think. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207067835-How-to-open-project-from-the-network-share