# PhpStorm: This file doesn't belong to the project

Tags: phpstorm

After merging current branch to `Dev` branch and push, PhpStorm shows all project as follow for all project files, it says it doesn't belong to the project and project files in the left menu has a highlighted colour indicating they don't belong to the project.

[image]

I already read solutions given in [In IntelliJ, How Do I Fix "These Files Do Not Belong to the Project"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099716/in-intellij-how-do-i-fix-these-files-do-not-belong-to-the-project/38073757) and [File doesn't belong to this project - PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853069/file-doesnt-belong-to-this-project-phpstorm) but non-works for me.

I also deleted the entire `.idea` folder and Invalidate/Cache Restart but it doesn't work

Comment: This is definitely something wrong with your `.idea`. Could be some IDE issue (config file corruption). Similar recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66760987/783119 -- try again precisely as described there.